# How to run all the test files in a directory with Rake, from the command line?

Tags: ruby, command-line, rake

I have some test folder:

```
app/
  test/
    folder1/
      test1.rb
      test2.rb
    folder2/
      test2_1.rb
      test2_2.rb
      test2_3.rb
```

I want to run only the tests from the 'folder2' directory (not only one tests file), from the command line (without implementing a Rake TestCase). Not with ruby on rails.

I tried:

```
rake test TEST=test/folder1/test*.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pattern, the asterisk must be escaped.

Solution:

```
rake test TEST=test/folder1/test\*.rb
```